# regex to remove bbcode tags with atrributes

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, bbcode

I've got a number of bbcode tags that have phpbb attributes (5 digit value - assuming text color or something).  They look like this in the text:

```
This is [b:31747]bold[/b:31747] text and so is [b:17171]this[/b:17171].
```

I cannot get a regex working that finds `bracket+b+colon+any_combo_of_5_digits+end_bracket` and lets me replace it with corresponding html. Using php's preg_replace() function, if it makes a difference.

Comment: Do you wish to remove just the start and end tags? Or do you wish to remove the contents too?

Comment: keeping contents, replacing tags with corresponding html.  the \ in front of the d was the missing ingredient.

Comment: Once you have a good answer, you should "check" it off. This lets everyone know that your question/problem is resolved, (and gives credit where credit is due).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regular expression you need is:

```
\[/?b:\d{5}]
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work with both opening and closing tags for any type of tag:

```
$string = preg_replace("/\[(\/?[a-zA-Z]+):[\d]{5}\]/is", "<$1>", $string);
```

Comment: Still too exact for me, what I ended up using: `preg_replace("/\[(\/?[^\[\]]+):[a-z0-9]+\]/is", "[$1]", $string);`

Answer (score 1):

This would replace bold, underline and italic tags.

```
$new_text = preg_replace('~\[(/?[bui]):\d+\]~is', '<$1>', $text);
echo $new_text; // This is <b>bold</b> text and so is <b>this</b>.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace("/\[\/?b:[0-9]*?\]/","","[b:17171]this[/b:17171]");
```

http://ideone.com/fDCZM