# Regex to replace PHPbb url to HTML

Tags: html, regex, bbcode, sar

I'm trying to search and replace URL's coming from a PHPbb dump into the correct HTML format. I'm using [sublime text's Regex](https://github.com/dmikalova/sublime-cheat-sheets/blob/master/cheat-sheets/Regular%20Expressions.cheatsheet) but can use another platform if you have any tips.

**Example source**

```
[url=https://example.com/example]URL Text[/url]
```

**Result i'm looking for**

```
<a href="https://example.com/example">URL Text</a>
```

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27459103/phpbb-bbcode-to-html-regex-or-otherwise) article but the example does not work for me. Due to my inexperience with regular expressions I've not been able to find a solution. Any tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to replace the BBcode URL's with the following Python regex in Sublime:

**Search:**

```
\[(url=)(.*?)\](.*?)\[/url]
```

**Replace:**

```
<a href="\2">\3</a>
```